# Sampling distribution of AUC in multivariate normal distribution

Tags: sampling, auc, multivariate-normal-distribution

[image]

[image]

I need to derive the sampling distribution of the above equation, which is sample mean of the AUC from what I see. The first picture describes the distribution of the data, which I understand is multivariate normal. However, I am not sure how to approach this problem.

The best I could find online is how to find sampling distribution for mean and variance, which didn't really help me understand the problem.  How would one derive the sampling distribution for AUC mean?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First calculate the distribution of each $\mathbf{G}_i'\mathbf{Y}_i$. $\mathbf{G}_i'$ is a constant and $\mathbf{Y}_i$ is multivariate normal, which means that (by a standard result), $$\mathbf{G}_i'\mathbf{Y}_i \sim N(\mathbf{G}_i'\boldsymbol{\mu}, \mathbf{G}_i'\boldsymbol{\Sigma}\mathbf{G}_i)$$

Second, sum the $\mathbf{G}_i'\mathbf{Y}_i$ over all $i$. The $\mathbf{G}_i' \mathbf{Y}_i$ have independent normal distributions. When independent normal distributions are added the means and variances are summed to get $$\sum_{i=1}^m \mathbf{G}_i'\mathbf{Y}_i \sim N\left(\sum_{i=1}^m \mathbf{G}_i'\boldsymbol{\mu}, \sum_{i=1}^m \mathbf{G}_i'\boldsymbol{\Sigma}\mathbf{G}_i)\right)$$

Third, divide by $m$. When a normal distribution is divided by a constant, the mean gets divided by the constant, and the variance gets divided by the constant squared: $$\dfrac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^m \mathbf{G}_i'\mathbf{Y}_i \sim N\left(\dfrac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^m \mathbf{G}_i'\boldsymbol{\mu}, \dfrac{1}{m^2}\sum_{i=1}^m \mathbf{G}_i'\boldsymbol{\Sigma}\mathbf{G}_i)\right)$$

Fourth, if you are who I think you are and taking the class I think you're taking, you're welcome ;-)